# How to set HTTP/2 in Heroku and Vapor4

Tags: vapor

I have this configuration:

```
let tls = TLSConfiguration.forServer(certificateChain: domainCert, privateKey: .file(keyPath))
app.http.server.configuration.tlsConfiguration = tls
app.http.server.configuration.supportVersions = Set<HTTPVersionMajor>([.two])
```

And on localhost HTTP/2 protocol work well:
[image]

But when this code is deployed to Heroku, the site crashes and I see this error:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

HTTP/2 [is not currently supported](https://help.heroku.com/JAOCNZ25/does-heroku-have-plans-to-support-http-2) on Heroku so you'll need to enable HTTP/1 support in your app